# create html table and have table header span more than one column

Tags: html, vba

I am sending an e-mail from excel using outlook. For the body of the e-mail I am making use of HTML.

I had a table which was working fine. However I have been asked to add a header above the current header of my table. The header is called "Premium / (Discount)". So the code below does that fine. However I would like for this header to span across two columns and centre.

I am using the line below but it is not working, why?

```
"<th colspan='2'>Premium /(Discount)</th>


msg = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;'><tr><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th>" & _
    "<th colspan='2'>Premium /(Discount)</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th><th>&nbsp</th></tr>" & _
    "<tr><th align='left'>Fund</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Market Spread %</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Tolerance</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Bid %</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Ask %</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Tolerance</th><th>&nbsp;</th>" & _
    "<th align='left'>Extra Notes</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>"
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do here, and why so many empty cells?

Comment: I was using the empty cells so the headers wouldn't be so close to each other. I'm guessing there is some kind of padding function I can use? I would like the "Premium / (Discount)" header to centre over the Bid % and Ask % column headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your code, your table has a total of 14 columns, so your colspan should be of `14` instead of `2`.

Also, you're using some of these columns as space : `<th>&nbsp;</th>`. Note that you can do it better by adding a cell-padding value (in pixels) to your `<table>`, so your table will look like this : http://cssdeck.com/labs/qyh7ytdi.

Here is the code that should do the trick:

```
msg = "<table style='font-size: 12pt;' cellpadding='5'>" & _
      "<tr><th colspan='3'></th><th colspan='2'>Premium /(Discount)</th></tr>" & _
      "<tr><th align='left'>Fund</th>" & _
      "<th align='left'>Market Spread %</th>" & _
      "<th align='left'>Tolerance</th>" & _
      "<th align='left'>Bid %</th>" & _
      "<th align='left'>Ask %</th>" & _
      "<th align='left'>Tolerance</th>" & _
      "<th align='left'>Extra Notes</th></tr>"
```

Comment: thanks that's much better than what I had written. The cellpadding obviously works in all directions. Is there a way just to space the headings. I.e. the rows in my table and now spaced out

Comment: I'm affraid it's not possible since it adds a padding to the whole column, and not for each cells... You cannot have a header cell with a different width than the cells from the others row and in the same column

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<body><table style='font-size: 12pt;'><tr>
    <th></th><th></th><th></th><th colspan='2'>Premium /(Discount)</th><th></th><th></th></tr>
    <tr><th align='left'>Fund</th>
    <th align='left'>Market Spread %</th>
    <th align='left'>Tolerance</th>
    <th align='left'>Bid %</th>
    <th align='left'>Ask %</th>
    <th align='left'>Tolerance</th>
    <th align='left'>Extra Notes</th></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

This will help "Premium / (Discount)" header to centre over the Bid % and Ask % column headers no matter the width of the columns.

**NOTE: It won't center it the whole table.**